# Using a VJSON to parse a FB friends list in C++, running into memory issues, how would I fix this?

Tags: c++, parsing, pointers, malloc, xcode4.5

I'm working on a project which takes your Facebook friends list in JSON format, parses it, and loads it into certain data structures.

In this case, I'm putting it into an arrayList.  I'm using a library that our professor found online and recommended that we use, called [VJSON](http://code.google.com/p/vjson/).  I'm only a sophomore computer engineering student, so most of the stuff in those libraries are kind of above my head, along with everyone else in the class. Yet he recommended that we use it anyway.

The VJSON class parses the JSON text file and stores it in javascript objects.  You access these objects by starting with the "root" and proceeding to each next object in a linked list style format.

I've put the method down below that I used to collect the variables. Our professor also provided us with the everything up to the for loop. As you can see, at the bottom of the for loop, I've created a person and put it into my arrayList, which is working fine.  After successfully creating, storing, and printing around 14 people, though, it suddenly hits a runtime error.

I ran the project in xCode, here is the error it gives me:

```
Project2(4244) malloc: *** error for object 0x100103c18: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
 *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Obviously I can tell this is some sort of memory management issue, but not much beyond that.  I have no idea why any object would be freed; and if it somehow was freed, why weren't any of the others freed? In addition, I tried to run my project with an alternate text file, using a friend's list of friends.  It managed to get through about 30 people before getting the same error; why on Earth would it get through more of his friends than mine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  This VJSON stuff is really above my head.  Thank you!

```
arrayList createArrayList(string filename){
    arrayList people;

    ifstream fileInput(filename);

    //turn input stream into string

    // Black magic to turn input stream into string.  Remember to include streambuf header
    // This string constructor accepts an iterator to the start of the file input stream
    // and another one that represents the end of input character (which is supplied by calling the default constructor of the iterator).
    string inputStr((istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileInput)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    //parse file content into json object
    char *errorPos = 0;
    char *errorDesc = 0;
    int errorLine = 0;
    block_allocator allocator(1 << 10);

    json_value *root = json_parse(const_cast<char*>(inputStr.c_str()), &errorPos, &errorDesc, &errorLine, &allocator);

    //get the first element, data, this value is an array of JSON objects (people)
    json_value *list = root->first_child;

    //This outer loop addresses each person's JSON object
    for(json_value *it = list->first_child; it; it = it->next_sibling){
        //This inner loop looks at each key/value pair within each person object
        string first_name, last_name, birthday, hometownID, hometown, personIDstr;
        for(json_value *personKeys = it->first_child; personKeys; personKeys = personKeys->next_sibling){
            //If the key/value pair has a key of "first_name" collect value associated
            if(!string(personKeys->name).compare("first_name")){
                first_name = personKeys->string_value;


            }
            //collect last name
            else if(!string(personKeys->name).compare("last_name")){
                last_name = personKeys->string_value;
            }
            //collect birthday
            else if(!string(personKeys->name).compare("birthday")){
                birthday = personKeys->string_value;
                //trim bday to first five characters
                birthday = birthday.substr(0,5);
            }
            //collect hometown
            else if(!string(personKeys->name).compare("hometown")){
                for(json_value *homeKeys = personKeys->first_child; homeKeys; homeKeys = homeKeys->next_sibling){

                    if(!string(homeKeys->name).compare("id")){
                        hometownID = homeKeys->string_value;
                    }

                    if(!string(homeKeys->name).compare("name")){
                        hometown = homeKeys->string_value;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(!string(personKeys->name).compare("id")){
                personIDstr = personKeys->string_value;
            }
            //create person object based on which values are included

        }

        Person person(birthday, first_name, last_name, hometown, 0);
        cout << person << endl;
        people.insert(people.size(), person);
        cout << people.get(people.size()-1) << endl;
    }
    return people;
}
```

Comment: On what line of the code does it issue the error? You need to find out which object / pointer is affected by this, and then check your code to see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From https://code.google.com/p/vjson/

> Warning: vjson is destructive parser, i.e. you source buffer will be modified.

I think this may cause an error when `inputStr` dealocated.